# CUDA Thrust reduction with double2 arrays

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I have the following (compilable and executable) code using CUDA Thrust to perform reductions of `float2` arrays. It works correctly

```
using namespace std;

// includes, system 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <typeinfo>  
#include <iostream>

// includes CUDA
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// includes Thrust
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

// float2 + struct
struct add_float2 {
    __device__ float2 operator()(const float2& a, const float2& b) const {
        float2 r;
        r.x = a.x + b.x;
        r.y = a.y + b.y;
        return r;
    }
 };

// double2 + struct
struct add_double2 {
    __device__ double2 operator()(const double2& a, const double2& b) const {
        double2 r;
        r.x = a.x + b.x;
        r.y = a.y + b.y;
        return r;
    }
 };

void main( int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int N = 20;

    // --- Host
    float2* ha; ha = (float2*) malloc(N*sizeof(float2));
    for (unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        ha[i].x = 1;
        ha[i].y = 2;
    }

    // --- Device
    float2* da; cudaMalloc((void**)&da,N*sizeof(float2));
    cudaMemcpy(da,ha,N*sizeof(float2),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    thrust::device_ptr<float2> dev_ptr_1(da);
    thrust::device_ptr<float2> dev_ptr_2(da+N);

    float2 init; init.x = init.y = 0.0f;

    float2 sum = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr_1,dev_ptr_2,init,add_float2());

    cout << " Real part = " << sum.x << "; Imaginary part = " << sum.y << endl;

    getch();

 }
```

However, when I change `float2` to `double2` in the `main` program, namely

```
void main( int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int N = 20;

    // --- Host
    double2* ha; ha = (double2*) malloc(N*sizeof(double2));
    for (unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        ha[i].x = 1;
        ha[i].y = 2;
    }

    // --- Device
    double2* da; cudaMalloc((void**)&da,N*sizeof(double2));
    cudaMemcpy(da,ha,N*sizeof(double2),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    thrust::device_ptr<double2> dev_ptr_1(da);
    thrust::device_ptr<double2> dev_ptr_2(da+N);

    double2 init; init.x = init.y = 0.0;

    double2 sum = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr_1,dev_ptr_2,init,add_double2());

    cout << " Real part = " << sum.x << "; Imaginary part = " << sum.y << endl;

    getch();

}
```

I receive an `exception` at the `reduce` line. How can I use CUDA Thrust reduction with `double2` arrays? Am i doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

**WORKING SOLUTION FOLLOWING TALONMIES' ANSWER**

using namespace std;

```
// includes, system
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

// includes CUDA
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// includes Thrust
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>

struct my_double2 {
    double x, y;
};

// double2 + struct
struct add_my_double2 {
    __device__ my_double2 operator()(const my_double2& a, const my_double2& b) const {
        my_double2 r;
        r.x = a.x + b.x;
        r.y = a.y + b.y;
        return r;
    }
};

void main( int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int N = 20;

    // --- Host
    my_double2* ha; ha = (my_double2*) malloc(N*sizeof(my_double2));
    for (unsigned i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        ha[i].x = 1;
        ha[i].y = 2;
    }

    // --- Device
    my_double2* da; cudaMalloc((void**)&da,N*sizeof(my_double2));
    cudaMemcpy(da,ha,N*sizeof(my_double2),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    thrust::device_ptr<my_double2> dev_ptr_1(da);
    thrust::device_ptr<my_double2> dev_ptr_2(da+N);

    my_double2 init; init.x = init.y = 0.0;

    cout << "here3\n";
    my_double2 sum = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr_1,dev_ptr_2,init,add_my_double2());

    cout << " Real part = " << sum.x << "; Imaginary part = " << sum.y << endl;

    getch();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known incompatibility with MSVC and nvcc. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/issues/detail?id=408) for example. The solution is to define your own version of `double2`  and use that instead.

Just for reference, I can compile and run your code correctly on a Linux 64 bit box with CUDA 5.5.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What is the reason for such an incompatibility? Does it involve also the latest versions of MSVC? In the quoted web page, it is suggested to define a customized version of `double2` as a `struct`. What about performance? In the past I have played a bit with my own version of `double2` as couple of `double` numbers, but I realized that a solution with a wrapper class internally using `double2`, instead of couple of `double`s, was faster.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Microsoft's compilers and libraries, so I can't really tell you more than what I offered in the answer. As for `double2` versus a struct - I take it you are not aware that `double2` *is* a simple struct (look in `vector_types.h`). There should be (and in my experience isn't) any difference in emitted code or performance in using a CUDA vector type and using your own functionally equivalent structure.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. Yes, I'm aware that `double2` is a `struct`, but there are special keywords in front of the definition: `__device_builtin__ __builtin_align__(16)`. As long as I know, they should allow for coalesced memory accesses. Would this provide some improvements over a customized definition not using alignment?

Comment: `__device__builtin__` is just a tag, it doesn't have any effect, and `__builtin__align__` resolves to the basic `__align__` macro. The CUDA "builin" vector types are just simple structures and they rely on compiler analysis to achieve coalescing, just like any user defined type. The only place they have any real meaning is in relation to texture hardware, and even then only so that the type size and alignment matches what the texture APIs expect.