# CUDA / C++ : error C3861: 'uint2float': identifier not found

Tags: c++, cuda

I am experiencing this issue in Visual Studio 2012 using CUDA 5.5 with in the file "FLOAT_UTIL_DEVICE.HCU", which is provided by Nvidia. According to similar issues, it might be a matter of code structure, but i can't see any problems:

```
#include <vector_functions.h>
#include <device_functions.h>

//// ADDED BY ME FOR TEST PURPOSES
//inline __device__ float uint2float( unsigned int a )
//{
//  return (float) a;
//}
//// END

inline __device__ float2 uintd_to_floatd( uint2 a )
{
    return make_float2( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y) );
}

inline __device__ float3 uintd_to_floatd( uint3 a )
{
    return make_float3( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y), uint2float(a.z) );
}

inline __device__ float4 uintd_to_floatd( uint4 a )
{
    return make_float4( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y), uint2float(a.z), uint2float(a.w) );
}
```

The methods in question should be defined in "device_functions.h" according to Nvidia documentation. If i uncomment the test code (which defines the function which is missing), i get a new error: "more than one instance of the overloaded function "uint2float" matches the argument list"; hence somehow it IS defined already. What am i missing?

Comment: Did you try adding the namespace before them?

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: @Peter: "error C3861: 'uint2float': identifier not found" is the full error message.

Comment: Really? No line numbers?  No description of what file it's in?

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, i thought that it was irrelevant (it's just my local paths). Of course: "Error 3 error C3861: 'uint2float': identifier not found c:\users\emher\dropbox\cuda\emil\parallel\lib\float_util_device.hcu 28 1 Msd"

Comment: And what is at line 28?  Are you trying to compile this from host code?  Where are you including it from?  Is your compiler set up to run this through NVCC first?

Comment: It would be good to know a little bit more about the code structure, and where `FLOAT_UTIL_DEVICE.HCU` is actually included, as requested by @Peter. Remember that `uint2float` is defined in `device_functions.h` and has a conditional compilation: `#if defined(__cplusplus) && defined(__CUDACC__)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem in CUDA 5.0 using gcc. If I take a complete repro case using your device functions:

```
#include <vector_functions.h>
#include <device_functions.h>

inline __device__ float2 uintd_to_floatd( uint2 a )
{
    return make_float2( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y) );
}

inline __device__ float3 uintd_to_floatd( uint3 a )
{
    return make_float3( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y), 
                uint2float(a.z) );

}

inline __device__ float4 uintd_to_floatd( uint4 a )
{
    return make_float4( uint2float(a.x), uint2float(a.y), 
                uint2float(a.z), uint2float(a.w) );
}


template<typename Tin, typename Tout>
__global__
void kernel(Tin *in, Tout *out) {
    out[threadIdx.x] = uintd_to_floatd(in[threadIdx.x]);
}

template __global__ void kernel<uint2,float2>(uint2 *, float2 *);
template __global__ void kernel<uint3,float3>(uint3 *, float3 *);
template __global__ void kernel<uint4,float4>(uint4 *, float4 *);
```

and compile it:

```
$ nvcc -c -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" uint2float.cu 
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelI5uint36float3EvPT_PT0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelI5uint36float3EvPT_PT0_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 7 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelI5uint46float4EvPT_PT0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelI5uint46float4EvPT_PT0_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 8 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelI5uint26float2EvPT_PT0_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelI5uint26float2EvPT_PT0_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 6 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]
```

it builds without any compile errors. This either means that there is another error in some code that you haven't shown us, or this is a problem specific to Visual Studio or the MS C++ compiler. Thrust code using certain vector types is [known to break when compiled with the VS toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18123407/681865). It might be that you are seeing a symptom of the same issue. If you are desperate for a short term fix, you might try defining your own version of the vector types and re-writing your __device__ functions to work with those types instead.