# float1 vs float in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have noticed that there is a `float1` struct type in cuda. Is there any performance benefit over simple `float`, for example, in case of using a `float array` vs `float1 array`?

```
struct __device_builtin__ float1
{
    float x;
};
```

In `float4` there is a performance benefit, depending on the occasion, since the alignment is 4x4bytes = 16bytes.
Is it just for special usage in `__device__` functions with `float1` parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recall that in a comment to a post of StackOverflow it was mentioned that `__device_builtin__` had no performance effect, but I could not find that post again.

Comment: I found the post: [CUDA Thrust reduction with double2 arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123407/cuda-thrust-reduction-with-double2-arrays).

Comment: I think it's just there to support developers doing compiler tricks to conserve source code when generating multiple sets of executable code for different sizes of tuple.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware Would you like to expand a bit your comment into a new answer complementing mine? It could be useful to future users and I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @talonmies' comment to the post [CUDA Thrust reduction with double2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123407/cuda-thrust-reduction-with-double2-arrays), I have compared the calculation of the norm of a vector using CUDA Thrust and switching between `float` and `float1`. I have considered an array of `N=1000000` elements on a GT210 card (cc 1.2). It seems that the calculation of the norm takes exactly the same time for both the cases, namely about `3.4s`, so there is no performance improvement. As it appears from the code below, perhaps `float` is slightly more confortable in use than `float1`.

Finally, notice that the advantage of `float4` stems from the alignment `__builtin__align__`, rather than `__device_builtin__`.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\transform_reduce.h>

struct square
{
    __host__ __device__ float operator()(float x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }
};

struct square1
{
    __host__ __device__ float operator()(float1 x)
    {
        return x.x * x.x;
    }
};

void main() {

    const int N = 1000000;

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vec(N,3.f);

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    float reduction = sqrt(thrust::transform_reduce(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), square(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>()));
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time reduction:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    printf("Result of reduction = %f\n",reduction);

    thrust::host_vector<float1>   h_vec1(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_vec1[i].x = 3.f;
    thrust::device_vector<float1> d_vec1=h_vec1;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    float reduction1 = sqrt(thrust::transform_reduce(d_vec1.begin(), d_vec1.end(), square1(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>()));
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time reduction1:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    printf("Result of reduction1 = %f\n",reduction1);

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: I agree with what you and talonmies said though I havent tested your code. Seems legit anyway.